# css3: Selecting the :before pseudo element when the link is active

Tags: html, css

I need to select the before pseudo element when the link is active,but I am able to select the before pseudo element when hovering the link.

[image]

On loading the page the first link(browse) is active and I need the same effect of hover while active.

To select the before pseudo element while hovering:

```
.breadcrumb a:hover:before {
   background: black;
   border: 1px solid white;
   color: white;
}
```

To select the before pseudo element while active(I am trying the below but it is not working):

```
 .breadcrumb a:active:before {
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
 }
```

please find the below jsfiddle for better clarity:
https://jsfiddle.net/diasraphael88/ygj40pn7/

Comment: It works. Maybe you are confusing `:active` with `:focus`?

Comment: can you please share the working link? Its still not working.

Comment: See your same fiddle but with red background: https://jsfiddle.net/ygj40pn7/1/. When you active the link, you see the red. So `:active` works.

Comment: It seems like you want to accomplish the `:focus` result. `:active` deals with element being clicked.

Comment: @Oriol : Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `active` class or `:hover` to accomplish this.

```
.breadcrumb a.active:before {
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

OR

```
 .breadcrumb a:focus:before {
        background: black;
        border: 1px solid white;
        color: white;
}
```

Comment: I have the same css in jsfiddle but its not working.

Comment: Like @Oriol said, you can use :focus too. I got it working in fiddle with the `active` class.

Comment: Thanks yardpenalty :). I missed that colon.

Comment: You're welcome. This is a great example for using pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`